Get info about rendered entities (mapnik) for each zoom
I'm using mapnik (mod_tile + renderd) to generate tiles based on data from PostGIS. The data is very simple, several countries with roads, names, etc. There is a style description file (xml), where the style is specified (classic OSM). Can I somehow get data about the rendered entities for each zoom? For example, on distant zooms only the names of large cities and countries are displayed, so I need to get this data (excluding those not rendered for these zooms).
I couldn't find any solutions or documentation.
Perhaps someone has encountered the need to solve a similar problem.

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images. Since you ask about different levels of detail your sample data should include multiple levels.
